# Sqlite database documentation templates / software?

Tags: sqlite, documentation-generation

I need to write documentation for several small sqlite databases. Want to describe how the data is used,  including table and row descriptions and sample data.

Is it possible to use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com)? If not are there any alternatives, or any templates I could work from?
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Using [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) is not possible since, as far as I know, it only supports exporting to SQLite. For a number of suggestions about free database managers you might want to take a look at [What are good open source GUI SQLite database managers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers) - a number of the GUIs mentioned there support report generation.

Definitely far more feature rich, but with a significant price tag, is [Navicat for SQLite](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_overview.html), which is an excellent database manager with report generation features.